# How can i add a Tooltip in chosen jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Hi iam working on chosen jquery plugin and i need to add tooltip to all the elements in chosen  plugin. I tried tweaking around in chosen but didn't get any positive result. Does anyone have any idea?

Code:

```
  <div id="synonyms_div" style="height:auto;width:170px;">
     <select id="tagger-tags" class="tagger-tags" multiple style="width:150px; font:7px;" tabindex="4">
                @foreach(var tag in ViewBag.tags)
                {
                    <option id="sel-tags" value="@tag.ID" parent="@tag.PARENT_ID" style="font:6px;">
                        @tag.NAME [@tag.EL_COUNT]
                    </option>
                }               
      </select>
    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".tagger-tags").chosen({ search_contains: true });

});
 </script>
```

Comment: What did you try "tweaking around"?

Comment: Adding title field on to search-choice class elements in chosen.jquery.js file...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after for the final result... Can you give an example?

Comment: What i am trying is to add a simple text tool tip as shown by @itcouldevenbeaboat below, for every element in chosen jquery plugin... I hope you are aware of chosen http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Comment: Then show your code, preferably in the form of a concise example.  See http://sscce.org

Comment: Please make some sort of effort. As it currently stands, the question comes off as very lazy. Also seeing your comments on other's answers is very discouraging...

Comment: That's what i am trying, its new for me at least give me some time to get habituated to the way all need it to be...i am sorry if its really bad in the way i am asking.

Comment: This site gives a TON of guidance for writing questions... you must have ignored all warnings and instructions when you hit submit.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: If its chosen plugin you have to use 
    jQuery(".tagger-tags").chosen({ search_contains: true });
     $('#tagger-tags').trigger('chosen:updated');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible solution without having to use any other libraries, or anything else... This can be accomplished with a bit of CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<!--// we have to wrap the select in a span to use :after with it //-->
<span class="tooltip" title="some title for your tooltip">
<select>
    <option>Something</option>
    <option>Something Else</option>
</select>
</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tooltip:hover:after {
    position: relative;
    /* we can get the title attribute from the relevant item */
    content: "" attr(title) "";
    /* style however you want */
    border: 1px dashed black;
    top: -1.5em;
    left: 12em;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

Will give you something like:

[image: chosen w/ tooltip]

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yvZuv/5/embedded/result/)**

Literally added the word `multiple` to the select box in order to modify it to fit OP's requirements...

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Sqzq5/1/embedded/result/)**

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: i would really appreciate your time and effort but here my application needs chosen plugin, i mean chosen has a good functionality of multi select which i am using. I want to add additional tooltip feature to it.. I hope you got what i am trying now?

Comment: That is with the chosen plugin. You didn't give any code, so I had nothing to go by. This can VERY EASILY be modified to suit your needs.

Comment: @user2593327, brbcoding has put 10 times the effort into writing his answer than you've bothered putting into your question.  You've only wasted his time through your lack of care & effort in constructing the question.  Please clarify and improve your question for everyone's benefit.  Thanks.

Comment: @brbcoding +1 for effort and taking the time to answer; not to mention, your answer is ***overly*** generous.

Comment: If its chosen plugin you have to use 
    jQuery(".tagger-tags").chosen({ search_contains: true });
     $('#tagger-tags').trigger('chosen:updated');

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but I'm almost positive you want to be using this:
http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Yeah that's the way to add to tooltips to various elements but i tried doing the same in the case of chosen plugin but it doesn't work. Do i need to change anything in chose.jquery.js files?